# how to replace string (with special characters) to normal string in vim

Tags: text, vim

Hi i am trying to replace a string with special character at the end with new string. For Example, I want to replace

```
qwerty_CRS_abc\
```

to

```
qwerty_CRS_abc
```

I tried with this:

```
:%s/qwerty_CRS_abc\/qwerty_CRS_abc/g
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Pattern not found: padring_CRS_CAN\/padring_CRS_CAN\g
```

Basically, I just want to remove that backslash in whole file. It should be just

```
qwerty_CRS_abc
```

Comment: have you tried `:%s|qwerty_CRS_abc\\|qwerty_CRS_abc|g`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`:%s/qwerty_CRS_abc\\/qwerty_CRS_abc/g`

Certain characters such as  `/&!.^*$\?` carry a special significance to the search process and must be escaped using the `\` character when they are used in a search. Hence the `\\` used to escape the backslash in your example.